# How can I launch the Maps app without leaving my app in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, maps

I have already published an iPhone app. On it, i have a button which closes my app and launches the "Maps" app.  This all works great, but I was wondering if it is possible to launch the Maps app within my app, so my app is not closed. For example, can I click a button and have the native Maps app slide in from the bottom?

I have researched this quite a bit, but all I have come up with shows how to leave my app, which I am already doing.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching the iPhone native Maps app with current location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010370/launching-the-iphone-native-maps-app-with-current-location)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html). You'll need to implement some of the MKMapViewDelegate methods to tell the view what you want to display.

Comment: Indeed; iOS has no concept of one app inside another app but the same map view as used in the Maps app is exposed via the MKMapView class.